# PHP: Get values from checked radio button

Tags: php

I have a little problem.

I would like to echo value/values selected in this:

As you can see Autobus and Tramwaj are selected. I would like to have an echo  in this format:
Autobus,Tramwaj

```
<div class="radiofield_box" style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="Autobus" name="komunikacja[]">
        <span class="radio_label" style="margin:5px 0px 0 10px;vertical-align:middle;">Autobus</span>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="Tramwaj" name="komunikacja[]">
        <span class="radio_label" style="margin:5px 0px 0 10px;vertical-align:middle;">Tramwaj</span>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Metro" name="komunikacja[]">
        <span class="radio_label" style="margin:5px 0px 0 10px;vertical-align:middle;">Metro</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm getting value from other file and trying to make it this way:

```
<?php echo $_POST['komunikacja']?>
```

but I'm getting only: Array.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You can get values from `$_REQUEST` variable of php.
As 'komunikacja' is an array, you should go through loop to get all it's values.

```
<?php
        $values = $_POST['komunikacja'];

        foreach($values as $key => $val){
        echo $val; 
        }
?>
```